# HADOOP: Failed to run hdfs namenoe -format

Tags: hadoop

When I run `hdfs namenode -format`, I meet an error:

```
hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 10: /opt/bmr/hadoop/bin/hdfs.distro: No such file or directory
```

And in `hdfs` file, I found the contest as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

export HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME:-/opt/bmr/hadoop}
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME:-/opt/bmr/hadoop}
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_YARN_HOME:-/opt/bmr/hadoop}
export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/libexec
export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS}"
export YARN_OPTS="${YARN_OPTS}"

exec /opt/bmr/hadoop/bin/hdfs.distro "$@"
```

Comment: How did you install Hadoop? Which OS is it installed on?

Comment: I installed hadoop on Centos.

Comment: Did you install using RPMs?

Comment: No, a special commercial package.

Comment: Ok. Does this return anything? `rpm -qf /opt/bmr/hadoop/bin/hdfs.distro`

Comment: No, the same error "file /opt/bmr/hadoop/bin/hdfs.distro: No such file or directory" occurs.